# Send Post request in java with JSON as raw data file (like in JMeter)

Tags: java, postman

So I've looked into many solutions here , but couldn't find this...

Say I have json file "myFile.json" - it hold the body of the request
Say I have this path as destination URL : "http://1.1.1.7:80/myService/publish"

All I want to do is send this file to the destination.

Here is a code I'm using (found it here in one of the threads)

```java
public class HttpClientExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String payload = "data={"myFile.json"};
        StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(payload,
                ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://1.1.1.7:80/myService/publis");
        request.setEntity(entity);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: please check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692166/http-post-in-java-with-file-upload

Comment: You should read the contents of the file -- what you've got here is just sending the text value of the filename, except for the syntax error where you didn't escape your double-quotes around the filename (`data={\"myFile.json\"};`)

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readString(java.nio.file.Path)